# Excel VBA for each selected row change value in column x

Tags: vba, excel

This should have been easy, but im struggling.

Looking for a fast code to apply on user selected range.

For each row user has selected set new value in column x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Test()
 Dim Rng As Range
 Set Rng = Selection
 For Each rr In Rng.Rows
  Range("X" & rr.Row).Value = "new value"
 Next
End Sub
```